# Roundcube shows net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) error

Tags: apache, roundcube

I just upgraded roundcube from ver 1.3.6 to 1.3.8. Now it shows the error : net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden) for some js files.

I have tried giving permission to dir. But, not working

Error log from console :

```
hyracorp.com/:16 GET /webmail/program/js/app.min.js?s=1540293174 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
hyracorp.com/:17 GET /webmail/program/js/jstz.min.js?s=1553508884 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
hyracorp.com/:14 GET /webmail/program/js/jquery.min.js?s=1553508884 403 (Forbidden)
hyracorp.com/:15 GET /webmail/program/js/common.min.js?s=1540293174 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
hyracorp.com/:16 GET /webmail/program/js/app.min.js?s=1540293174 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
?_task=login:17 GET /webmail/program/js/jstz.min.js?s=1553508884 net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
?_task=login:38 Uncaught ReferenceError: rcube_webmail is not defined
    at ?_task=login:38
(anonymous) @ ?_task=login:38
jquery-ui.min.js?s=1540293173:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery-ui.min.js?s=1540293173:6
    at jquery-ui.min.js?s=1540293173:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js?s=1540293173:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js?s=1540293173:6
?_task=login:99 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at ?_task=login:99
```

Answer (score 0):

First I though it was a permission issue. I gave permission to the dir for user www-data. It didn't resolved the issue. After searching a lot, found the solution on roundcube forum.

By **removing** the **.htaccess** files [fixed the issue](https://www.roundcubeforum.net/index.php?topic=15232.0).

After remove the .htaccess file, if you see this error "roundcube issue : connection to storage server failed", please run `sudo dovecot`

Answer (score 0):

If your roundcube is setup under Apache2 and alias as in:

```
# /etc/apache2/conf.d/roundcube.conf
Alias /webmail /usr/share/roundcube
```

or similar - make sure the default virtual host is enabled `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`.

Weird issue, but this has helped me after X hours of trying different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove all .htaccess file (as suggested by @jinto-antony), it's better to comment following line in it:

```
#Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

Or fix symlink owner of "program" folder to match apache user.

```
chown -h user:group program
```